# Terraform modify a resource once created

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-cloudfront, terraform-provider-aws

I am creating a `cloudfront` distribution using `terraform` and I get this error:

> error creating CloudFront Distribution: CNAMEAlreadyExists: One or more aliases specified for the distribution includes an incorrectly configured DNS record that points to another CloudFront distribution. You must update the DNS record to correct the problem.

But once I created the cloudfront "**without any alternative names (aliases in terraform language)**" and once it is created and try to edit it and add the `alternative names` it doesn't give the above error.

So I thought of creating the cloudfront first and then create other resources and then after sometime update the created cloudfront with `aliases`

Is this possibe? What is the workaround? Why the first time it is failing (with same alternative name) but once created and add the same alternative domain again it works?

Here's my cloudfront.tf

```
resource "aws_cloudfront_distribution" "aws_cloudfront_distribution" {
  # aliases = var.CF_ALIASES

  default_cache_behavior {
    allowed_methods = ["GET", "HEAD"]
    cached_methods  = ["GET", "HEAD"]
    compress        = "true"
    default_ttl     = "0"

    forwarded_values {
      cookies {
        forward = "none"
      }

      query_string = "false"
    }

    # lambda_function_association {
    #   event_type   = "origin-response"
    #   include_body = "false"
    #   lambda_arn   = var.CF_LAMBDA_ARN
    # }

    max_ttl                = "0"
    min_ttl                = "0"
    smooth_streaming       = "false"
    target_origin_id       = var.CF_BUCKET_ORIGIN_ID
    viewer_protocol_policy = "redirect-to-https"
  }

  enabled         = "true"
  http_version    = "http2"
  is_ipv6_enabled = "true"

  origin {
    custom_origin_config {
      http_port                = "80"
      https_port               = "443"
      origin_keepalive_timeout = "5"
      origin_protocol_policy   = "http-only"
      origin_read_timeout      = "30"
      origin_ssl_protocols     = ["TLSv1", "TLSv1.1", "TLSv1.2"]
    }

    domain_name = var.CF_BUCKET_DOMAIN_NAME
    origin_id   = var.CF_BUCKET_ORIGIN_ID
  }

  price_class = "PriceClass_All"

  restrictions {
    geo_restriction {
      restriction_type = "none"
    }
  }

  retain_on_delete = "false"

  tags = var.CF_TAGS_LIST

  viewer_certificate {
    acm_certificate_arn            = var.CF_CERTFICATE_ARN
    cloudfront_default_certificate = "false"
    minimum_protocol_version       = "TLSv1.2_2018"
    ssl_support_method             = "sni-only"
  }

}
```

And how can I update the same cloudfront with alternative name in terraform?

Comment: Which properties are you trying to edit?

Comment: I am only trying to edit the `aliases` property to add an alternative name

Comment: I tried to replicate your issue, but the only way I could do it is to have pre-existing CF distro with the same CNAME which you want to use in new distro. Obviously you can't have two different CF distros using same CNAME alias. So the question is, do you have any other CF distro beside the one you are trying to create in this question?

Comment: No, I don't have any `CF` with the `CNAME` i am about to use.